# How to ask a user for Sheets input, validate and process data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

**Issue**

Colleagues gather information on fairs and such and that information needs to be submitted. Currently they copy-paste this data in a Sheet and some data validations and such are applied on this sheet. However, data validation does not reject the input in case it's not an accepted value when you paste 2 or more values (it just gives a warning by marking the upper-right corner red). Furthermore, we are not able to set certain columns required.

Since this sheet is automatically imported in a database, it is important to have all required data present and with valid values.

**Question**

Would it be possible to have a Google Sites page that shows a Google Sheet, allows you to add data to this sheet and process this data when a submit button is clicked on the page?

**Thoughts**

I was able to find the Sheets integration in Google Sites, but the first issue I encounter is that users are not able to add data to this sheet through the Google Site.

I thought about doing this just in Sheets instead of a Google Sites solution, but this has some drawbacks:

- Using a script would require user rights to edit the sheet that's automatically imported
- Not very user friendly for simultaneous usage
- Not an attractive interface

I'm not asking for a complete solution, but as I failed to find such a possibility I'd appreciate references to relevant documentation or opinions how this problem may be solved in the best way.

Comment: When the data validation was set-up was the `reject input` checked for the `On invalid data:` option? [default is `Show warning`]

Comment: @random-parts yes it is. It rejects the value as you'd expect it to, provided that you type the value or paste one value (e.g. change one cell). However, my colleagues usually gather the information in an Excel file or similar and afterwards copy paste all the data to this sheet. In that case, the data validation just gives a warning.

Comment: You said that this data it automatically imported to a database.  Is that performed by a script? If so, why not do the data validation there.

Comment: The data is published as CSV and the database imports that data so that's not an option. (and immediate feedback to the user is required when input does not validate)